# Use array as a dataProvider to populate DataGrid not working AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var lista:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
var tablaarray:Array = new Array();
var externalfile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://las.api.pvp.net/api/lol/las/v1.4/summoner/by-name/goncyrlz?api_key=MYKEY");
var textloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(externalfile);

lista.columns = ["id","name","profileIconId","summonerLevel","revisionDate"];
lista.setSize(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
lista.x = 0;
lista.y = 0;

textloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, agregar);
function agregar(event:Event):void
{
    var textoCargado:String = textloader.data;
    tablaarray = textoCargado.split(",");

    trace(tablaarray.toString());
    lista.dataProvider = new DataProvider(tablaarray); 
    addChild(lista);
}
```

The response on the trace is:

```
{"goncyrlz":{"id":96893,"name":"GoncyRlz","profileIconId":590,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1402143493000}}
```

but the datagrid is empty (but with 5 rows), why it's this?

Answer (score 0):

{"goncyrlz":{"id":96893,"name":"GoncyRlz","profileIconId":590,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1402143493000}}

is a single item object where tablaarray.goncyrlz = {"id":96893,"name":"GoncyRlz","profileIconId":590,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1402143493000}

try lista.dataProvider = new DataProvider(tablaarray.goncyrlz);